# Rails - Override Alias method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is a smelly code and the alias method has been used at many places . Now I would want to call the actuals rails .destory method thereby deleting all assocaited dependents of Books - Is there a way I could ignore the alias method and call the .destory AR method ?

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  def disable
    self.is_active = false
    save!
  end
  alias_method :destroy, :disable
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an attempt at implementing paranoia mode, I guess. Smelly code, indeed. It overwrites `destroy` method and you can't call the original implementation anymore (easily). But you can save the original implementation!

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_method :ar_destroy, :destroy
  alias_method :destroy, :disable
end
```

Now you can call `book.ar_destroy` to invoke AR's `destroy` implementation. Although, getting rid of the alias would be a better solution.

Comment: I came up with  dataset.run_callbacks(:destroy); dataset.delete! . However liked your answer much better. Getting rid of the alias ..hmm I know - very tedious task though - not knowing the in-out of app. Anyhows Thanks much !

Comment: nice addition about 'easily':)

Comment: @Ilya: yes, added it after seeing your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Ruby >= 2.2, you can use `Method#super_method`:

```
book.method(:destroy).super_method.call
```

In this case, you'll call AR method instead of alias. It's a quick fix, but I suggest to refactor your code.